# UIScrollView like Twitter app for iPad

Tags: ipad, twitter, uiscrollview, custom-controls

I'm looking for a tutorial or for some ideas to make a custom controller that looks like the one in the Twitter app for iPad, I mean the stacked pages with a main menu on the left. Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: That's a pretty intense undertaking. If you do come up with any cool ideas, I suggest you post your work in a Github repo so we can all work together and improve it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

we had created a mock project and added in github

https://github.com/raweng/StackScrollView

Comment: Ya for some reason we turned it to private .. in mean time you can get the fork project of mine https://github.com/reefaq/StackScrollView, else aaron had made the excellent update on top of StackScrollView https://github.com/aaronbrethorst/StackScrollView .. :)

Comment: Downloaded the zip - compiled - runs great.  Thanks for the leg up!

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution for this.

Place a table view as a sidebar menu on the left side.
Place a scroll view on the top.
Add content into scroll view.

The scroll view will cover the table view.
Set the width of content size of the scroll view to the sum of the content width and the sidebar width.
The content position is at ( sidebar width, 0 ).  You could drag it to cover or reveal the sidebar.

The problem is the table view could not receive any touch event for it is covered by the scroll view.

So I implement a subclass.

```
@interface UICascadeScrollView : UIScrollView {
        UIView* passthroughView_;
}

@property(nonatomic,assign) IBOutlet UIView* passthroughView;

@end

@implementation UICascadeScrollView

@synthesize passthroughView = passthroughView_;

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        for( UIView* v in self.subviews ) {
                if( CGRectContainsPoint( v.frame, point ) ) {
                        // one of the sub view could accept the touch event
                        return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
                }
        }
        CGPoint newPoint = [self convertPoint:point toView:passthroughView_];
    return [passthroughView_ hitTest:newPoint withEvent:event];
}


- (void)dealloc {
        self.passthroughView = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Change the scrollview class to UICascadeScrollView and set the passthroughView to sidebar.

That's all.

==================================================================================

A sample of three cascade layers with a table view as a sidebar.

git@github.com:slavikshen/CascadeScrollView.git

https://github.com/slavikshen/CascadeScrollView

This is my first commit to git hub.  Pls tell me, if there is anything wrong.

Comment: The solution works, however it doesn't handle horizontal dragging over the tableView to scroll the UICascadeScrollView, like you can with the Twitter iPad app. Any tips on handling that trick?

Comment: Put an UICascadeScrollView A in another UICascadeScrollView B as content. Set A.passthroughView = B.

Comment: Nope, that just hitTests UICascadeScrollView A as before.