# Route touch event to view beneath UIScrollView if swipe gesture is not recognized - like iPad Twitter app

Tags: ipad, ios, twitter, uiscrollview, transparent

Let's say I've got this view hierarchy.  Note this is very similar to the Twitter iPad app, so take a look at that as a reference.

```
 Views on top:
+--------------------+
|      |      |      |
|      |      |      |
|  S1  |   V1 |  S1  |
|      |      |      |
|      |      |      |
+--------------------+

 Views beneath
+--------------------+
|      |             |
|      |             |
|  T1  |    V        |
|------|             |
| B  B |             |
+--------------------+
```

V1: An opaque view, a subview of scrollview S1.
S1: UIScrollView, filling up bounds of window, with transparent background. Only needs to scroll its contents horizontally. Note the rectangles either side of V1 are transparent.
T1: A UITableView, underneath S1 (visible)
B: A UIButton, underneath S1 (visible)
V: The root view, with child views: T1, B, B, S1

I would like to replicate behaviour similar to the Twitter iPad app, specifically:

• If I horizontally drag anywhere in S1 (even the transparent areas) it scrolls horizontally.

• If I interact with T1 or tap B buttons, they behave normally

Note that the answer at [UIScrollView like Twitter app for iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066712/uiscrollview-like-twitter-app-for-ipad) is close, but does not handle drag scrolling in the transparent areas of the top scroll view (S1).  This question is specifically about that problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this instead

> https://github.com/raweng/StackScrollView

this may help to solve ur problem !

it supports :

- Orientation (both Landscape & Portrait)
- Swipe Gestures
- Bouncing Effect